# Why does it say that these two values are not the same?

Tags: python-3.x

I have values of indexes from arrays which both are the number 1 being the 0th element in an array but yet when comparing them in an if statement the computer interprets them as not being the same.

This is just little segments from the code that i have but just wondering as to why this is happening?

```py
winningnumber = []
usernumber = []

def generatenumber():
    number = random.randrange(0,2) #Random number 0-2
    winningnumber.append(number)

def retrieve_and_validate():
    user_entry = choice.get()
    usernumber.append(user_entry)

firstelement_win_num = winningnumber[0]
firstelement_user_num = usernumber[0]
print(firstelement_win_num)
print(firstelement_user_num)



if(firstelement_win_num == firstelement_user_num):
    print("Exact number")
else:
    print("number isnt exact")
```

so lets say that the user inputted number is equal to the random generated number being 1 for example. This is the output of the result.

1

1

number isnt exact

Comment: Are they both the same type? I'm thinking one of them is a str and the other is an int

Comment: Well the number generated by rand is set to int automatically i think yes?

And as for the other value

# Entry for the users number
choice = Entry(window)

Is the entry saved as a string?

Comment: Try `usernumber.append(int(user_entry))`

Comment: @Blake, if you want to check for yourself you can check the documentation of whatever you're using to get the user's entry or (more easily) `print(type(user_entry))`

Comment: If this is part of a bigger tkinter program, consider using a tk.IntVar instead of a tk.StringVar to ensure you receive an int whenever you retrieve the value with .get()

Comment: @101arrowz , that worked, surprisingly simple fix , thanks

Comment: @SyntaxVoid , I will also implement this into further code thankyou.